# Get SQL Server query to return zero records instead a single null record for aggregated no group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, aggregate

Does SQL Server have a means to return no records if a group aggregate results in zero records instead of a single record with nulls and 0?

The problem SQL statement:

```
select  
    Max(InterfaceID), Count(*)
from 
    (select InterfaceID 
     from interface 
     where interfaceid = 99) as Interfaces
```

Problem result

```
+-------+---------+
| i_max | i_count |
+-------+---------+
| NULL  |       0 |
+-------+---------+
```

Example if a group by is specified

```
select  
    Max(InterfaceID), Count(*)
from 
    (select InterfaceID 
     from interface 
     where interfaceid = 99) as Interfaces
group by 
    interfaceid
```

Result:

```
+-------+---------+
| i_max | i_count |
+-------+---------+
```

Can you get the second result with the first query, no group by specified?

This is all because Entity Framework model, and data handling empty array instead of an array 1 record, but of little use.

Comment: Add a having clause. Like HAVING MAX(InterfaceID) > 0 or something along those lines, whatever works for your actual data.

Comment: Both the queries you passed have GROUP BY clauses, and will return zero rows.  I assume you meant to omit the GROUP BY in the first query, in which case it summarizes the subquery, and a single row with (null,0) is the correct result.  Can you elaborate on the EF issue you are facing?

Comment: thanks - removed GROUP BY on the first query.

Comment: This is simply retrieving a count - if you're using EF, why are you even messing with a SQL script/sproc?  `dbContext.Interfaces.Where( i => i.InterfaceId == 99 ).Count()` isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can modify you query like -

```
select  Max(InterfaceID), Count(*)
from (
  select InterfaceID from interface where interfaceid=99
) as Interfaces
having  Max(InterfaceID) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `HAVING` you can also add `GROUP BY ()` - the below will return 0 rows if there were no matching rows in the input, or a single row result aggregating all rows in the input otherwise.

```
SELECT   MAX(InterfaceID),
         COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT InterfaceID
                 FROM    interface
                 WHERE   interfaceid = 99) AS Interfaces
GROUP BY ()
```